# How can I write a switch statement in R?

Tags: r, geospatial, raster

I am not able to write a switch statement correctly. And the examples available are not helpful. Basically, the statement should check what the value in a cell is (Choices: 1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128) and based on that increase/decrease the row and column number. Some switch statements have 2 calculations.

```
library(raster)
fdr<-raster("fdr.tif")
row1<-50
col1<-50
cell1<-fdr[row1,col1] #The point of origin
switch (cell1,
        4={row2 = row1 + 1
        },
        2={row2 = row1 + 1 & col2 = col1 + 1
        },
        1={col2 = col1 + 1
        },
        128={row2 = row1 - 1 & col2 = col1 + 1
        },
        64={row2 = row1 - 1
        },
        32={row2 = row1 - 1 & col2 = col1 - 1
        },
        16={col2 = col1 - 1
        },
        8={row2 = row1 + 1 & col2 = col1 - 1
        }
)
```

I am open to techniques other than a switch statement as well. Or any idea to make it faster. Eventually I'll wrap this into a function and do it for every cell (pixel).

Data:

1. FDR raster (small file): https://www.dropbox.com/s/7o3y8w01y6zqqwm/fdr.tif?dl=0
2. The concept is water flow direction: http://courses.washington.edu/gis250/lessons/hydrology/index.html#coded

Comment: I think you'll need to return a vector not do assignments in switch, although you might be able to do that with `<<-`.

Comment: Thank you. If you could provide some more info, it will be helpful. I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I tried replacing all = with <<-. Though the code ran without errors, but I don't see any output named col2,row2

Comment: Are you aware of the `terrain` function in `raster` package?

Comment: Barely. I have never used it.

Comment: You should give it a try

Comment: Also, if you are working in geographic information, this site might be useful: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r

Answer (score 2):

This is how you write your `switch` and get it to return a vector of row, col:

```
row1 <- 50
col1 <- 50
cell1 <- 16

rowcol <- switch(as.character(cell1),
                 '4' = c(row1 + 1, col1),
                 '2'   = c(row1 + 1, col1 + 1),
                 '1'   = c(row1, col1 + 1),
                 '128' = c(row1 - 1, col1 + 1),
                 '64'  = c(row1 - 1, col1),
                 '32'  = c(row1 - 1, col1 - 1),
                 '16'  = c(row1, col1 - 1),
                 '8'   = c(row1 + 1, col1 - 1))

rowcol

> rowcol
[1] 50 49
```

You don't want to be doing a `switch` for each element of a large raster repeatedly; it will be glacial. Here is a vectorised operation that starts from any row/col and does a single update/move

```
## generate some dummy raster data
set.seed(1)
m <- matrix(sample(2^(0:7), 9, replace = TRUE), ncol = 3)

## collect row and column indices for raster
dd <- cbind(r = as.vector(row(m)), c = as.vector(col(m)))

## look-up matrix for row and col shifts
lu <- matrix(c( 0,  1,
                1,  1,
                1,  0,
                1, -1,
                0, -1,
               -1, -1,
               -1,  0,
               -1,  1), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
## set rownames with powers of 2 to allow indexing using `m`
rownames(lu) <- 2^(0:7)

## need `m` as a vector
mc <- as.character(as.vector(m))

## which cell to move to next given values of `m`
move <- dd + lu[mc, ]
move
```

which gives

```
> move
      r c
 [1,] 2 1
 [2,] 3 1
 [3,] 3 0
 [4,] 0 3
 [5,] 3 3
 [6,] 2 3
 [7,] 0 4
 [8,] 1 2
 [9,] 2 2
```

Which is correct given the input data. Now you have the problem of making the next move and keeping track of things. In this example, the move would shift you to cells outside the raster for 3 of the 9 cells (the ones with a 0 in `r` or `c` and hence if you indexed back into `m` to get the power of two in the cell *moved too*, you only get 6 values returned

```
> m[move]
[1]   4  16  32  32 128   2
```

Hence you'd need to keep track of this as you walk, but this should get you started.

Comment: Thanks a lot! As an aside, is this the fastest way to accomplish this or should I look at alternatives too? I'll be doing this over thousands of US national rasters. Thanks again.

Comment: Am just working though something for a matrix that would be vectorised. You *don't* want to do anything but a trivial sized raster with a switch. So I wouldn't be so quick with the accept; if you leave it unaccepted, others may chime in.

Comment: Oh, thank you! Yes, the rasters are CONUS-wide. I intend to "walk" from one cell to the most downstream cell by wrapping this in a function. And do the same operation for a) all cells within one raster, b) repeat for all rasters. Thank you for helping.

Comment: OK @maximusdooku added an example of doing the walk. The **raster** package has a `terrain()` function that returns the powers of 2 data you have here so I would look and see if it has anything suitable that you might use.

Comment: Oh thanks a ton! I am going through it right now. This might be a noob question. But in my case, I would do a as.matrix('fdr,tif') before starting, right?

Comment: If `r` is your raster then `as.matrix(r)` should convert it to something like `m` used in my example.

Comment: When I did it over the raster I provided in the question, I run into problems because of NAs(I think), which your examples doesn't have. "subscript out of bounds" when I do: move <- dd + lu[mc, ] ...............